# save audio file with background music

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am developing an application for `recording audio` and `play` it with a beat in background and also save it for further use, right now i am just able to play it with background using two instances of `AVAudioPlayer` but when i am going to save them i had no idea how to because these are two different sound file ,now only way to save it is to merge both file but i had no idea how to mix them. Ideas and Suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

i did the audiotask, just check that and tell what help you what you need

Comment: basically i have two audio files and i have Mix both of them and save it on another file..